# How to access BlueStacks' localhost from Windows?

Tags: networking, android-emulator, bluestacks

After some research I managed to access Windows' localhost from Bluestacks. If I open Google Chrome in BlueStacks and type 10.0.2.2:/... I can access Windows' localhost.

How do I do this the other way around? Is there a way to connect to Bluestacks' localhost from Windows?

Comment: Usually an emulator acts like a separate PC, hence it's localhost interface is not available outside of the system itself. That you can access the host's localhost from within BlueStacks is because the emulator has created a virtual IP address within the emulated system.